# Mysql Set the result of a query to clipboard (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to automate a way to set the result of a query to clipboard. Is there a way to set the result of a query to clipboard?

Comment: Php is an Scripting language, you need to assign the php result to a JS variable and then can copy it to the clipboard. Use https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp for doing it in JS

Comment: @RohitDalal - Why PHP? There are also other languages and tools. This question is unclear / broad.

Comment: My Bad I thought you were using PHP, It can be any backend or even front end language not just PHP

Comment: @RohitDalal thanks for the suggestion but I'm trying to do it using mysql only. Thanks!

Comment: You are running SQL on some server or in browser only?

Comment: @RohitDalal nope, through micrsoft sql server management studio

Comment: You don't. You use a programming language. Such as writing a python script to connect to the db, execute the query and copy the resulting dataset to the clipboard. Or an Excel macro, or any other programming language.  SSMS is for doing things manually, it's not an automation tool.  So, that begs the question, why does this have to be in SSMS?